# Is there any books for Guitars that how to play any song western song/ east song(indian bollyhhood) song?

Tags: guitar

Is  there  any books  for Guitars  that  how to play any song   western song/ east song(indian bollyhhood)  song ?

or  is  there  any  you  tube  channel  for this ?